# Removing random element from array and adding it to another array: OutOfIndex bound error

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

What is wrong with this code?
I am trying to pick a random element from an ArrayList and move it to another ArrayList to create a permutation. It keeps giving me out of bounds errors.

```
int size = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * (size));
        
    random.remove(r);
    permutations.add(random.get(r));
    size--;
        
}
```

Comment: if you check your stacktrace (the error message in the console) you will see in which line you have the error, please when asking also put this information in your questions

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the order of the instructions first you are removing from position r and you try to get from position r.

```
    permutations.add(random.get(r));       
    random.remove(r);
```

Moreover, If you want to remove from collections as arrayList I do recommend to use Iterators. Iterator has methos as next() for getting the next element in the array and remove() for removing the actual element you can check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: because if you have random and you remove from position r, then you have nothing in random position r.